# I am running an instance of mongodb in docker. How do I get the connection string to use it with RoboT3 or mongoose in my nodejs application?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am running an instance of mongodb in docker. How do I get the connection string to use it with RoboT3 or mongoose in my nodejs application?

I want to be able to get a connection string like this

mongodb://dbuser:dbpassword@examplehost:63639/name

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct it yourself following the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/).